# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.hateoas.Resource even though I have the dependency added

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have the following in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But I still get the following message

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/hateoas/Resource
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:668) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.hateoas.Resource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

I tried deleting the contents of the `.m2` folder and downloading all the dependencies again. I tried force updating the maven project, but I still get the message when I start the Spring Boot project. Anyone know why I'm getting this even though I have added the dependency?

Answer (score 9):

For Spring Boot use [spring-boot-starter-hateoas](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-hateoas-tutorial) dependency

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
>   <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Comment: Surprisingly I still get the message

Comment: I think this has to do with one of the community dependencies I'm using. The error went away when I removed it. I contacted the author to look into the issue

Comment: @arya do you have exclusions?

Comment: Ain't solution, if you use :spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.0 is not gonna work ,  really depends the dependencies you are using, since i use spring-boot-starter-data-rest, is useless to add this dependency ...

Answer (score 2):

Add following dependency in pom.xml

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
```

Write following method in your controller:-

```
@GetMapping("/student/{id}")
public EntityModel<Student> getstudent(@PathVariable int id) {
    Student student = studentRepo.findById(id).orElse(new Student());
    EntityModel<Student> resource=new EntityModel<Student>(student);
    Link link=WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(this.getClass()).
              slash(studentRepo.findAll()).withSelfRel();
    resource.add(link.withRel("all-students"));
    return resource;
}
```

Comment: EntityModel<user> resource=new EntityModel<user>(user);
  WebMvcLinkBuilder link=WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(WebMvcLinkBuilder.methodOn(this.getClass()).retrieveAllUsers());
     resource.add(link.withRel("all-students"));
   resource.add(link.withRel("all-users"));
   return resource;

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting container if you added hateoas explicitly, that worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

The ResourceSupport/Resource/Resources/PagedResources group of classes never really felt appropriately named. After all, these types do not actually manifest resources but rather representation models that can be enriched with hypermedia information and affordances. Here’s how new names map to the old ones:

ResourceSupport is now RepresentationModel

Resource is now EntityModel

Resources is now CollectionModel

PagedResources is now PagedModel